# Disallowed for cross-origin requests that require preflight

Tags: instagram, sails.js

```
     module.exports.cors = {

    allRoutes: true,


    origin: '*',

    credentials: true,

    methods: 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS, HEAD',

    headers: 'X-Requested-With,content-type'
};
```

Getting error when using Instagram auth API.
Above is my "cors.js" In which I allows all request , but it didn't work. Please , tell me if you have already done this type of work.

```
  XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:1337/api/v1/instagram/auth. The request was redirected to 'https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=5238d8f3c0284df3a5d724f…2Fv1%2Finstagram%2Fcallback&response_type=code&state=a%20state&scope=likes', which is disallowed for cross-origin requests that require preflight.
```

Comment: Is this client side script connecting with the instagram API? then it has nothing to do with sails.

Comment: NO this is server side scripting , written using sails js.

Comment: So that error is being generated on the server? Because it looks like it is being generated in the browser. It looks like your client is sending a request to your server and your server is redirecting that request to instagram and the browser does not like that.